# $_REQUEST information not being passed through in IE

Tags: php

I am having a bizare problem where I have a script that works elsewhere on the site but refuses to work for me now. The problem is exclusive to IE, it works fine in Mozilla.
Below is the form:

```
<form class="element_form" action="general_image.php" method="post">

    <?php generate_input('hidden', '', 'id', $id);?>
    <input type="image" src="../images/delete.gif" name="action" value="delete" class="button" />
    <input type="image" src="../images/tick.gif" name="action" value="active_switch" class="button" />

</form>
```

Here is the code that is supposed to work:

```
<?php

include('header.php');

$db->connect();

$table = 'general_image';

$page = 'general';

$region = $_SESSION['region'];

$action = $secure->secure_string($_REQUEST['action']);
$id = $secure->secure_string($_POST['id']);

$max_active = 1;

if($action == 'active_switch' || $action == 'delete'){

    $response = array();

    $response['action'] = $action;
    $response['id'] = $id;

    if($action == 'active_switch'){

        $query = 'SELECT * FROM general WHERE region = "' . $region . '"';

        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if(!$result) {

            $utility->fail($action, 'query error: ' . $query);

        }else{

            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            $already_active = false;

            $active = '';

            if($id == $row['fifi']){

                $already_active = true;
            }

            $active .= $row['fifi'];

            $response['results'] = $active;

            if(!$already_active){

                $update = '';
                $active = '';

                $update .= 'fifi="' . $id . '"';

                $active .= $id;

                $query = 'UPDATE general SET ' . $update . ' WHERE region = "' . $region . '"';

                $response['results'] = $active;

            }else{

                    $utility->redirect($page . '.php');

            }
        }

    }elseif($action == 'delete') {

        $query = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=" . $id;
    }

    echo $query . "hello";


    if(!mysql_query($query)) {

        $utility->fail($action, 'query error: ' . $query);
    }
```

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great. Thanks

EDIT

```
$action = $secure->secure_string does the following:

    function secure_string($string)
    {   
        return (strip_tags(addslashes(mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($string)))));
    }
```

Comment: what this func do $secure->secure_string ?

Comment: I fount this forum thread that might be interesting: http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3342151.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found that sometimes it is better to have a hidden field for action then a submit button or image. if someone press RETURN or ENTER to submit the form which action will be returned ?

Comment: You can't press enter to submit the form. It's click only.

Comment: I've gone for the simple, extra hidden field and two forms approach as it has solved the problem in this case. Thanks dude!

Comment: sorry i didn't spot that, in the case of an image field, the x,y coordinates of the mouse click are appended to the variable name, so you will end up with $_REQUEST['action_x'] rather then 'action' as you expected. see 
http://nz.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.form-image

Answer (score 1):

For example, the button image has: `name="submitP"` and `value="Print"`

In the FORM post PHP, I used so:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submitP']) || isset($_REQUEST['submitP_x']))
{ something....
}
```

If this second clause is to treat post IE

Answer (score 0):

Are you remembering to `session_start();` ?

Answer (score -1):

I think input[type='image'] is broken in IE. Try to use the button[type='submit'] instead.

Comment: no idea why my answer got downvoted cause a search for 'ie input image value' (http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ie+input+image+value) concur with my thought.